# Glassfish - connecting with OpenMQ to SonicMQ does not work

Tags: glassfish, jms, openmq, sonicmq

I have a glassfish instance running version 3.1.2. I need to connect to a remote server via JMS. The remote system - i think - uses SonicMQ.

I have a JAR an example (from the remote servers company) with that I can communicate with the remote server without problems.

I think I've configured my glassfish correct but a connect to the remote sever is not possible. I always get the same error when connecting / using the glassfishs ping function:

```
WARNING: [I500]: Caught JVM Exception: java.io.EOFException: Trying to read 40 bytes. Already read 32 bytes.
SEVERE: MQJMSRA_MC4001: constructor:Aborting:JMSException on createConnection=[C4000]: Packet acknowledge failed. user=user123, broker=remote.server.com:12506
SEVERE: com.sun.messaging.jms.JMSException: [C4000]: Packet acknowledge failed. user=user123, broker=broker=remote.server.com:12506
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ProtocolHandler.writePacketWithAck(ProtocolHandler.java:748)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ProtocolHandler.writePacketWithReply2(ProtocolHandler.java:510)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ProtocolHandler.hello(ProtocolHandler.java:963)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ProtocolHandler.hello(ProtocolHandler.java:904)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionImpl.hello(ConnectionImpl.java:576)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionImpl.openConnection(ConnectionImpl.java:2443)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionImpl.init(ConnectionImpl.java:1094)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:454)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.UnifiedConnectionImpl.<init>(UnifiedConnectionImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.XAConnectionImpl.<init>(XAConnectionImpl.java:64)
    at com.sun.messaging.XAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(XAConnectionFactory.java:97)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ManagedConnection.<init>(ManagedConnection.java:196)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(ManagedConnectionFactory.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:426)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:1086)
    at org.glassfish.connectors.admin.cli.PingConnectionPool.execute(PingConnectionPool.java:130)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateExecCommand.executeCommand(TemplateExecCommand.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateCommandGetResource.processGet(TemplateCommandGetResource.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor180.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:184)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

WARNING: RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ jms/MyFactory ], MQJMSRA_MC4001: constructor:Aborting:JMSException on createConnection=[C4000]: Packet acknowledge failed. user=user123, broker=remote.server.com:12506
SEVERE: RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:4949/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool'; attrs = '{id=jms/MyFactory}'
```

Port 12506 is correct because there is no PortMapper. The `AddressList` parameter is `mqtcp://remote.server.com:12506` instead of `mq://remote.server.com:12506`

Googled half the day for a solution but didn't find anything. Has anyone a suggestion? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found another solution, for my problem. I'm now using the code from sample app without defining glassfish resources, this works fine.